# Ubuntu 22.4.1 where did the screen grab go?

Tags: boot

Just did the upgrade to Unbuntu 22.4.1 Very nice upgrade. You solved all of my problems.
Ubuntu now works like a real OS as I can move files from desktop to folders or trash or back again.

My only question is where did you hide the screen grabber as that can no longer be found.
It use to be in Utilities, I had it displayed on the dock. Since the upgrade it can not be found.
Thanks
John Six, proving that I can crash any OS on any day just by being me.

Comment: Does hitting the `Print Screen` key helps?

Comment: if you want the old screenshot tool, it is `gnome-screenshot` and isn't installed by default now that screenshot functionality is built into gnome.

Comment: Thanks, I re installed it.
To all who worked on this upgrade, great job!
It acts like an operating system now.
Now how do I close this?

Comment: print screen opens the grabber but then it saves to a "clipboard" and I have no clue where the clipboard is. Never found it in windows either.

 I did install the old screenshot, then one of the updates, removed it or buried the icon somewhere where I can't find it.